# My ProgressBar won't update

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

No matter what I do my progress bar won't update.

My XAML:

```
<Grid Height="25">
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            <!--EDITING HERE-->
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=PleaseWaitDialog, Mode=OneWay}"
                             Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
    <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Path=Percent}" />
</Grid>
```

Then in the ViewModel:

```
private double _percent;
public double Percent
{
    get { return _percent; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty("Percent", () => false, () => _percent = value);
    }
}
```

Then I set the value with:

```
_profileService.ApplyProfile(_data, (s, d) => UpdateApplyProgress(s, d, pleaseWaitVm));
```

and the update is:

```
private void UpdateApplyProgress(string message, double percent, CUDialogVM dialogVm)
    {
        //Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => dialogVm.Progress = percent));

        dialogVm.Percent = percent;
    }
```

I tried it with the dispatcher and it still didn't work.  I have also tried setting the value explicitly and nothing. Also I have checked in the debugger and the viewModel's Percent property is being set and the PropertyChangedEvent is being fired.

The SetPropertyMethod:

```
protected bool SetProperty<T>(string propertyName, Func<bool> areEqual, Func<T> setValue)
    {
        VerifyPropertyName(propertyName);

        if (!areEqual.Invoke())
        {
            setValue.Invoke();
            RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
            IsChanged = true;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

As per H.B. below my binding now is:

```
<ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Percent}" />
```

Comment: Does the view-model class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: Does the class for Percent property implement INotifyPropertyChanged and does SetProperty raise the Property Changed event?

Comment: Read the last sentence of the question...

Comment: Yes It inherits off of the base class that the rest of our ViewModels inherit from.

Comment: Yes it does I have traced it on the debugger. I have added the set property code above.

Comment: You set the property twice btw, i do not think you need that other line in the setter, as `SetProperty` takes care of it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ProgressBar.Minimum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.rangebase.minimum.aspx) and [`Maximum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.rangebase.maximum.aspx) defaults are `0` and `1`, are your values in that range? If not change those properties accordingly.

Comment: I set those properties in the XAML and it still won't update.

Comment: @twreid: What are your values for the property, what did you set min and max to? Are there [binding errors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx)?

Comment: The min is 0 and the max is 100. No, I have no binding errors at all.

Comment: @twreid: Is the `ProgressBar` even visible at all? (As in has some visible value that does not change, or how do you determine that the update does not happen?)

Comment: On the dialog that I display I see the long grey bar at the bottom, but it never fills up. I even tried adding a loop from 1 to 100 right after the window is shown and updating the Percent by one to see if maybe it was because of a Closure that was causing this and it still didn't update.

Comment: @twreid: Then i still suspect that the binding is off, binding errors are not necessarily thrown, e.g. if there is no `DataContext` then bindings to it are just ignored. You could temporarily put a `Loaded` event on the PB and check if the `sender` actually has a `DataContext` containing your view model.

Comment: I did that and it does contain the viewmodel.

Comment: I also set the value to 50.0 in the loaded and it didn't load half the bar. Also I noticed that _glow, _indicator, and _track are all null on the progress bar in the debugger.

Comment: @twreid: Weird. If you set the `_percent` field to `50` by default, does it show up?

Comment: @twreid: Regarding those fields being null: Do you have a default template for the `ProgressBars` which is just broken? (Should have been my very first question: Does `<ProgressBar Value="0.5"/>` display as expected?)

Comment: Wow yea when I do <ProgressBar Value="50"/> half the bar is filled when the window loads.

Comment: Actually I think maybe it is or the style is because I turned NotifyOnSourceUpdated and listened for that event and the progressbar Value was being updated from my view model, but the bar wasn't drawing the progress.

Comment: @twreid: Well, the template could have a `Binding` with `Mode=OneTime` or some non-sense like that. Is a custom template in use? If it is the default template that should not be the case.

Comment: The Progressbar has no custom style or datatemplate, but we have several custom templates and styles for other controls on this window so I wonder if somehow one of them may be causing  a conflict?

Answer (score 0):

Try that in your XAML:

```
 <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Path=Percent, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Moreover, the `ProgressBar` values have to be between 0 and 100!